# Is there a way to use custom procedural textures in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Is there support for generating procedural textures in Cycles using, say, Python scripting?

The built in procedural textures are very limited.

Comment: Great question! I've wondered myself... I'll bet the new OSL shaders will offer that ability, but I actually know nothing about them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned, Open Shading Language is likely what you are after. The Blender Wiki has good OSL info. In addition, you may want to check out:

[www.openshading.com](http://www.openshading.com)

If OSL is not your thing, you may want to check out the many Blender procedural experiments (incl. Python) by Jimmy Gunawan at: [blendersushi.blogspot.com](http://blendersushi.blogspot.com)

Comment: Is it supposed to be in Japanese?